# Does 'raise' alone make the program terminate or not?

Tags: python, exception

I am reading a piece of code that retrieve data from a database. The 'result' is supposed to contain database records retrieved.

```
   try:
        for record in result:
            products.append(record['p'])
    except ServiceUnavailable as exception:
        logger.error("{query} raised an error: \n {exception}".format(
            query=query, exception=exception))
        raise
```

In Python, the 'raise' keyword will make the program terminate or not when an exception occurs? If it terminates, should I remove the 'raise' and only log this error so that a single database retrieval failure shouldn't crash the whole system. Is that right?

Answer (score 0):

A bare `raise` rethrows the exception caught in the `except` block. Whether or not the program will terminate depends on the caller - if it catches and handles this exception, the program could continue running. If it doesn't, the program will terminate (abnormally).

Comment: If I don't want this to terminate and I can change this code, and if I simply remove the 'raise', the program will not crash. Right?

Comment: @marlon if you don't `raise`, the exception is caught, and the program won't terminate.